# ASP Identity - AddToRoleAsync

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a problem using the Microsoft AddToRoleAsync() function.
For usernames where there is a hyphen in them I cannot get it to work successfully. For example:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser();
var email = "name-surname@company.com";
user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, "Admin");
```

I don't get an error thrown, the user just doesn't get added to the role and an entry never appears in the AspNetUserRoles.

However, as soon as I remove the hyphen in the email / username the AddToRoleAsync() works perfectly, which seems strange as this function takes an Id and role name.

We have the same value for both the email and username field.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: debug and see if there is any error coming

Comment: I managed to inspect the result and found there was an error. Hypens are not allowed as part of the Identity username. Thanks - @VikasRana

Comment: Have you tried to pass only the User?